# Connecting to MySQL using a token

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to connect to an RDS instance using the `sqlalchemy` library using a token. According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#generating-dynamic-authentication-tokens) it should be possible via the `cparams['token']` variable, but doing so I get an error of an unexpected argument.

Going deeper into the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-databases-with-access-tokens), there was this code where the connection could be established using the keyword argument `attrs_before`, but in this case such argument also does not exist.

Does anyone has any idea on how to connect to the DB using a token?

I've trying to do it via such code but with no effect:

```py
import boto3
import struct
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='xxx')
rds = session.client('rds')

def get_authentication_token():
    return rds.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname='xxxx', Port=3306, DBUsername='xxx')

engine_url = URL.create(drivername='mysql+pymysql', host='xxxx')
engine = create_engine(engine_url)

#@event.listens_for(engine, 'do_connect')
#def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
#    token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token)}s', len(token), token)
#    cparams['attrs_before'] = {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: token_struct}

@event.listens_for(engine, "do_connect")
def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    cparams['token'] = get_authentication_token()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with Session() as session:
    result = session.execute('select now()').first()
```

To be more precise I get the error:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what solved for me was replacing `token` with `password`:

```
@event.listens_for(engine, "do_connect")
def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    cparams['password'] = get_authentication_token()
```

Another remark is that you must also pass the SSL certificate in the connection, I simply added another param:

```
@event.listens_for(engine, "do_connect")
def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    cparams['password'] = get_authentication_token()
    caparam['ssl'] = {"ca": "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"}
```

Bear in mind that you might have to pass the full path to the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file. If you don't pass the SSL file and the connection param you'll still get an `Access Denied` even if everything else is setup correctly.

The SSL file can be downloaded from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem